# Java Logging only latent or errored calls

Tags: java, logging, log4j, log4j2

Logging and log filtering is a solved problem and many libraries provide this out of box. But the filtering most of libraries provide is based on current context of log statement i.e. log level or MDC value or Class name etc. Is it possible to filter logs in hindsight? i.e.

let's say call graph looks like this

```
methodA() -> methodB() -> methodC()
```

Each of methodA, methodB, methodC has a log statement in it. I want to log all of them if time overallTime taken in methodA is greater than X or if we caught an exception in methodA.

This will make sure that I can add aggressive log statements in my application, still the logs getting printed would be fairly less.

This might even be considered an antipattern considering the logs have to be stored in application buffer till the time we decide to print or drop them.

Comment: I'm not aware of any libraries that do this. For what its worth, it epically fails the 'hard crash' rule, _or_ it's useless: Either the log framework writes these to a temporary file (incurring just as much of a penalty), or it doesn't, and a VM or computer hard crash makes the logs poof out of existence. I don't think that's a showstopper, but it -might- explain why log frameworks aren't exactly knocking the door down to add this. I'd look into logging via TCP to another system on local net to solve these issues more thoroughly.

Comment: @rzwitserloot is it possible(are there frameworks?) that can achieve this out side logging frameworks? for example logging library may still log everything but there is a periodic job which filters higher latency logs from log file

Comment: Why don't you add a correlation id to your log statements, ingest them into a log analysis tool and filter there? That way you could look for processes that have run into an error or were slow and look at their statements.

Comment: this is next best option, as the log analysis tool like splunk are very costly.

Comment: Well, the ELK stack (Elasticsearch, Logstash, Kibana) should be free.

Comment: Another, somewhat more radical, option might be to use events as log statements. For example, you could publish the "log" events to a broker like Kafka and use Kafka Streams to join events on correlation id (and most importantly the "A ended" event that might contain the exception or timing), filter them and publish the important ones into a topic. Then have a consumer that writes the filtered events to any storage you like (file, database, log analysis system etc.).